# C# FTP library vs FTP command line application

Tags: c#, command-line, ftp

I have an option to use either the C# FTP library or the standard FTP command line application to connect and to retrieve data from an FTP server.

Can some one advice on what to prefer.?

Thanks.

Comment: I would think that unless you have a specific reason to use the command line FTP, then you're better off using the C# library if you're using C#.

Comment: This really depends on your own needs, so we can't make a preferation for you. A better question would've been "what are the differences?" and leave the choice up to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why would you be using a commandline tool, intended for end users, from code? You'll be having a hard time reading and parsing `stdout` and `stderr` to get the responses or errors that result from your commands.

Just use the [`FtpWebRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ftpwebrequest.aspx) and [`FtpWebResponse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ftpwebresponse.aspx) since they provide in a decent, easy-to-use interface that contains error checking and so on.

Answer (score 2):

Try to stay in a language's idiom where possible, so use a library when you can. Errors will be handled using C#'s Exceptions rather than checking some obscure command-line errorlevel value.

Answer (score 2):

Using a Library, you have access to the classes, events, exception handling and so on, which integrate much better with your code. I would say that's more maintainable than having to interpret the text output and return codes of a commmand line application. So my suggestion is to use the library.